# Соединить и отфильтровать массивы в select

Tags: jquery

Подскажите у меня есть 2 массива данных, которые соответствуют друг другу (название и адрес): 
1.Title, 
2.URL. 
В массиве Title есть пустые значения их хотел бы удалить и оставить только "актуальные", во втором массиве есть URL, тоже есть значения и часть этих значений соответствуют пустым в Title, мне бы хотелось в select собрать значения по Title=text, Value=URL, пишу кодом так, текст (Title) нормальный, но результат в значении (URL) [Object, Object]:

```js
//В массиве arr1 (Title), такие значения:
var arr1 = ['Name1','Name2','Name3','','','','','',''];
//В массиве arr2 (URL), такие значения:
var arr2 = ['URL1','URL2','URL3','URL4','URL5','URL6','URL7','URL8','URL9'];
//Результат [Object, object] в значении
$('#View').append($('<option>', { 
value: arr2,
text : arr1
}));
//Результат в значении нормальный только Title
$('#View1').append($('<option>', { 
value: arr1,
text : arr1
}));
//Результат в значении нормальный только URL
$('#View2').append($('<option>', { 
value: arr2,
text : arr2
}));
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="View"></select>
<select id="View1"></select>
<select id="View2"></select>
```

Comment: Можно весь код увидеть?

Comment: А зачем весь код? задачу я описал полностью, есть выходные данные и их нужно отфильтровать и соединить в select.

Comment: Затем что бы понять в каком виде ваши входные данные? и как работают функции.Вот уже как бы нормально вопрос

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan зачем для этого **весь код**? Нужен **минимальный** (но самодостаточный и воспроизводимый, да) пример кода. Не стоит эти три условия на код называть как **весь**.

Comment: А сейчас я поправил этого недостаточно?

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov массивы у вас в одном количестве всегда?

Comment: Да, массивы в одном количестве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что вы впихиваете в `option` целый массив, а не циклом проходите по нему, и второе то что вы должны всегда проверить что бы соответствующие значение не были пустыми в обоих массивах.

Вот рабочий пример кода:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                
                //В массиве arr1 (Title), такие значения:
                var arr1 = ['Name1','Name2','Name3','','Name5','','','',''];
                //В массиве arr2 (URL), такие значения:
                var arr2 = ['URL1','URL2','URL3','URL4','','URL6','URL7','URL8','URL9'];
                //Результат [Object, object] в значении
                function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
                    if(arr2[index] != '' && element != ''){
                        $('#View').append($('<option>', { 
                            value: arr2[index],
                            text : element
                        }));
                    }
                }
                arr1.forEach(logArrayElements);
                
                
            });
        </script>
        <select id="View"></select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov Вы так хотели?

Comment: большое спасибо ))